# how to write method for mapping lists in viewmodel and display collection in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to display a collection of all products (using a view model) in my `Pro()` method

Models

```cs
public class Product
{
    public Product() { this.AddDate = DateTime.Now; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Product name")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Product Description")]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get ; private set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Category")]
    [Display(Name="Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location")]
    public bool location { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPicture
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Select Picture")]
    public string pictureurl { get; set; }
}
```

View model

```cs
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Product Description")]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; private set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Category")]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location")]
    public bool location { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductPicture> ProductPictures { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method

```cs
 public ActionResult pro()
 {     
     ProductViewModel product = new ProductViewModel();
     var pro = db.Products.ToList();
     if (pro != null)
     {
         product.ProductName = pro.ProductName;
         product.ProductDescription = pro.ProductDescription;
         product.Payextra = pro.Payextra;
         product.location = pro.location;
           product.ProductPictures = db.ProductPictures.Where(m => m.ProductId == pro.Select(m=>m.ProductId));       
     }
     return View(product);
}
```

Currently this is throwing the following exception

since i am trying to map complete list with a single object "=" operator can not be applied to int to IEnumerable. logically i am doing something wrong , so please help me to select current id from IEnumerable and map with current productpicture list and at last create the collection of same viewmodel which can be displayed in view.

Comment: What problem are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: i havent tried anything significant yet just r&d, i dont know how can i map productpicture list with id from product list and create a list again which can be displayed in razor view or should i just create logic in view itself ?, i am trying combinations but still no result :(

Comment: It's not clear what part your having struggling with? Are you wanting to return one existing `Product` with its associated `ProductPictures`, (for display or editing) or are you creating a new `Product`? Your `Pro()` method makes no sense - `var pro = db.Products.ToList();` returns a collection of products so `product.ProductName = pro.ProductName;` will throw an exception because `List` does not contain a propeprty named `ProductName`.

Comment: yes right exactly i am trying to find out same thing basicaly logic is product.ProductName = pro.ProductName (with where clause map the value of current product id) but how to write the code for same?

Comment: actually the code for controller is from details view where i can get value of single product using id parameter but now i want to retrieve whole list of products... hope you are getting me

Comment: this is the line from details view   var pro = db.Products.Find(id); so how can i do the same for list

Comment: Then for a start you should follow normal naming conventions and name the method `Index()` or something that indicates your displaying a collection. If you edit your question to (1) explain that you want that method to return a collection of all Products, and (2) add the details of the exception your getting, I will add an answer.

Comment: please check the edit..

Comment: Not good enough. I will edit in a moment to address the first item from my last and then you can complete the second part.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your efforts :)

Comment: See update - fill in the exception details your getting an I will add the answer.

Comment: That is not the error your getting. The code will not even compile because you get _System.Colections.Generic.List[Product] does not contain a definition for 'ProductName' ..._ (but will add an answer anyway shortly)

Comment: Thanks a lot .... you are a life saver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the method to project the collection of `Product` to a collection of `ProductViewModel` and return that to the view.

```
public ActionResult Pro()
{
    var pictures = db.ProductPictures;
    var model = db.Products.Select(p => new ProductViewModel
    {
        ProductName = p.ProductName,
        ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription,
        ....
        ProductPictures = pictures.Where(x => x.ProductId == p.ID)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Then in the view

```
@model IEnmerable<ProductViewModel>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductName)</th>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var product in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => product.ProductName)</td>
                ....
```

Side note: I recommend you change the name of the method to `Index()` which means a user can navigate to it using `.../Products` (assuming your using the default routing), or at least to a name that indicates your displaying all products (the current url will be `../Products/Pro` which does not convey any useful meaning to a user)

Comment: wow you are officially life saver but can you tell me if i just want to select one field from productpictures rather than a list how can i do that? i mean instead of IEnumerbale i used string picture and retriving only pictureurl then how to do it??

Comment: Not sure I understand what your mean. But best guess is you want your `ProductViewModel` to contain `public IEnumerable<string> PictureUrls { get; set; }` and then your query will be `PictureUrls = pictures.Where(x => x.ProductId == p.ID).Select(x => x.PictureUrl)`. If I have misunderstood, you will have to ask a new question with bit more explanation of what your trying to display in the view.

Comment: wow actually i was looking for single value for which i used firstordefault but was going to ask question for list but you solved it, can you suggest me a good book/site where i can learn complex examples of linq??

Comment: Can't recommend a book, but best to start with the MDN resources - [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) and there a hundreds of other good resources on the web.

Comment: great , thank you sir, i really appreciate your efforts :)